# Why is the .cache folder corresponding to the Maven .m2 folder lost in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus, spring-tool-suite

I had the following setup -

```
maven enabled in eclipse
with full index enabled and 
download repository index on start up checked
```

At the first it downloaded `nexus-maven-repository-index.gz` and I was able to search artifacts from eclipse itself.

However after couple of days I lost the `.cache` folder containing the `nexus-maven-repository-index.gz` file and now when I try to re-index it just shows

> "updating index central|http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"

It seems like this process never ends. How can I solve the issue so that I can be able to search artifacts on eclipse itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those index files are quite large with a few hundred megabytes each.

I don't think you have a way around this, you need to wait for the download to finish. I had to go through this a few times already and as far as I remember, Eclipse doesn't inform the download progress, which makes it even more annoying.

Comment: Hey Carlos can  you tell which eclipse are you using?? I found that indexing, downloading and building .cache folder is real quick and easy for kepler version  of eclipse but for later, the updating process is very long and hadn't had success for various attempts. Is it really the newer version of eclipse requiring more download time than the kepler version or is it due to some bug.In short, is it possible for newer than kepler  version of eclipse to fully update  index and work as I mentioned in the question?

Comment: sorry, I don't know much about Eclipse after Kepler since I started using IntelliJ IDEA